# Is the code that detects phantom button presses part of Android

Tags: samsung, boot

On one of my Samsung Tablets this morning, after signing in, the device would go to the lock screen after a second or so.  If I was quick, I could then press and hold the power button (intending to restart it).  Again, it would go back to the lock screen.  Sometimes I would see the **Power Off / Restart** buttons, but I was not fast enough to press them.

When I Googled I found this

> If you know the tablet is charged and it still won’t turn on, the standard method for resetting Samsung Tablets is to hold down the Power button and the Volume Down button until the boot cycle starts (about 10–15 seconds). Then release the buttons.

[How Do You Reset Your Samsung Tablet If It Won’t Turn On?](https://www.lifewire.com/turn-on-samsung-tablet-5184627)

**Question - Is this amazing code that detects phantom button presses a feature of Android?**  Or is it a Samsung artifact ?

### EDIT

It does not appear to be hardware, here is another link from 2017 [Complete Guide to Fix Samsung Tablet Problems](https://www.mobikin.com/android-recovery/fix-samsung-tablet-problems.html).  There are many more, and only in one case was it the hardware (digitizer).

Comment: I am sorry but your last sentence about phantom button presses doesn't fit to the rest of your question. If the power button doesn't work correctly the chance is high this is caused by a defect button.

Comment: If it was a defective button, the above sequence would not work.  And these solutions have been out there for years.  It is definitely a software issue.

Comment: It's unclear what is the relation between phantom button press with the quoted paragraph. The quoted paragraph didn't mention about the behavior that you described. Holding power + volume down will just force restart (not reset) the phone, if the buttons are working (I just tried it on Samsung Galaxy M21). Have you tried it?

Comment: On the other hand, to detect phantom/ghost touch on digitizer, turning on "Show taps" on "Developer options" will show the symptom.